# From PHP 7.2 to 5.3 backwards, command error

Tags: php

I'm running a script on localhost (XAMPP PHP 7.2) and it works perfect.
This script is for my schoolwork and school PHP server runs on PHP 5.3.3.
Running same script on school server produces the following error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in ... on line 42

I have tried to find answer but and I ended up learning that this error is very generic and could mean a host of things. I tried some re-fromatting of line 42 but with no success.

Script is not long and for sake of context I post all of it with Error line pointed out:

```
 <form style="max-width: 280px; padding: 0.5em; background-color: #fde"
      method="POST" action=<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>>

<?php 
function printSports() {
    $sports = <<< EOsports
        <p>Urheilu linkit:</p>
        <li><a href="https://www.bbc.com/sport" target="_blank">BBC - Sports</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.euronews.com/news/sport" target="_blank">Euronews - Sports</a></li>
    EOsports;
    echo $sports;
}

function printMusic() {
    $music = <<< EOmusic
        <p>Musiikki linkit:</p>
        <li><a href="http://www.mtv.com/news/music/" target="_blank">MTV Music</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://ultimateclassicrock.com/category/news/" target="_blank">Ultimate Classic Rock</a></li>
    EOmusic;
    echo $music;
}

function printCars() {
    $cars = <<< EOcars
        <p>Auto linkit:</p>
        <li><a href="https://www.motor1.com/news/" target="_blank">Motor1</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.motortrend.com/" target="_blank">Motortrend</a></li>
    EOcars;
    echo $cars;
}
?>

<select name="links[]" size="3" multiple>
  <option value="music">Musiikki</option>
  <option value="sports">Urheilu</option>
  <option value="cars">Autot</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" name="btn" value="Tulosta Linkit">

<?php
if (!empty($_POST['links'])){            **<<<<< THIS IS LINE 42 WITH ERROR**
    if (in_array("music", $_POST['links'])) {
        printMusic();
    };    
    if (in_array("sports", $_POST['links'])) {
        printSports();
    };
    if (in_array("cars", $_POST['links'])) {
        printCars();
    };
 }
?>

</form>

<a href="h2.html">TAKAISIN: Harjoitukset 2</a>
```

Comment: The closing `EOsports;` tokens must begin at the first position of the line, without any spaces and tabs before it, see the note on https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: Your school runs a dead PHP version...